# Control section-label an item is linked at in Rust

Tags: rust, kernel

I have been experimenting with writing kernel code in rust. While I could certainly use assembly and link it, it would be wonderful to be able to add a multiboot header in pure rust, like [this](https://github.com/andrewrk/HellOS/blob/master/hellos.zig#L14) in zig. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible as in write fixed bytes to a hard coded address? I think so but please clarify what you are asking. There are lots of `nostd` projects running for embedded systems booting in pure so a kernel is not impossible

Comment: @Simson I'm sorry that I don't know much of the language yet so this may be imprecise, but what I'd like to do is add bytes under the label `multiboot`. It's easy in assembly (just a `section .multiboot`) but I can't figure out how I could do it in rust

Answer (score 2):

You can control the section a function or static is placed into using the `link_section` attribute. Taken from [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html#the-link_section-attribute):

```
#[no_mangle]
#[link_section = ".multiboot"]
pub static BOOT: [u8; 2] = [0xEB, 0xFE];
```